# get file name with diacritic PHP

Tags: php, encoding, filenames, diacritics

there are a lot of topics about diacritics/accents in PHP but none of them solved my problem.
I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sk">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $items = scandir("test/");
                        echo $items[3];
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

$items[3] is ľšá.png but it displays: ÄŸÅ¡Ã¡.png

I tried:

```
foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $chr){
  echo mb_convert_encoding($items[3], 'UTF-8', $chr) ." : ".$chr."<br>"; 
}
```

But none of them is right for me.
I also tried to put this before scandir():

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mb_http_output('UTF-8');
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

But no change.

It is very strange because my website have always been working before I saw the issue (today) and I did not affect any code.

Comment: It works on localhost but not on hostin, with the same data, same files, same filenames,... Is it because of server configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You tried to convert **from** 1-byte encodings **to** UTF-8 (double-byte), but that wrong file name that you see has double characters in it, so its already UTF-8!
You need to convert it from UTF-8, and for me it worked like this:

```
mb_convert_encoding($items[3], "ISO-8859-15", 'UTF-8'); // its to ISO from UTF-8
```

Personally I use `iconv`

```
echo iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-15",$items[3]); // its from UTF-8 to ISO
```

but i think its no big difference if either of them actually works.

Also I suggest you to check file names on your webserver if they accidentally has been converted when uploaded.